# elasticsearch empty array search query with c# nest client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a model in elasticsearch like this:

```
"hits": [
{
  "_index": "post",
  "_type": "postmodel",
  "_source": {
    "projectId": "2",
    "language": "en",
    "postDate": "2017-06-11T08:39:32Z",
    "profiles": [
      {
        "label": "Emotional",
        "confidence": 1
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index": "post",
  "_type": "postmodel",
  "_source": {
    "projectId": "3",
    "language": "en",
    "postDate": "2017-06-11T08:05:01Z",
    "profiles": []
  }
},
...
```

By using c# Nest API, i want to fetch the postmodels that has empty profiles (the second post in the example data above). I have tried many ways to write the right query but i've ended up with this query below and still it doesnt give me the right results. My current code looks like this:

```
var postModels = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<PostModel>(s => s
        .Index("post")
        .Query(q =>
        {
            QueryContainer query = new QueryContainer();

            query = query && q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.ProjectId)
            .Query("3"));

            query = query && q.Nested(n => n.Path(p => p.Profiles)
                        .Query(qn => qn.Bool(b => b.Must(bm => bm.Match(m => m
                        .Field(f => f.Profiles).Query(null))))));

            return query;
        }));
```

I would be happy if someone can help me with this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/exists-query-usage.html#exists-query-usage) already?

Comment: Yes, i tried many variations of queries with aggregations, exists, missing,.. etc. the thing is all of them may work in the simplest way but my whole query is not simple. i am trying to add a new query to my existing query for every business requirement as you can see my code snippet above. so, it makes the query more complex and harder. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example of how you can accomplish it with an `exists` query in a `must_not` clause

```
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "post";

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(1)
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<PostModel>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Nested<Profile>(np => np
                        .Name(n => n.Profiles)
                        .AutoMap()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var posts = new List<PostModel>
    {
        new PostModel
        {
            ProjectId = "2",
            Language = "en",
            PostDate = new DateTime(2017, 6, 11, 8, 39, 32, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            Profiles = new List<Profile>
            {
                new Profile
                {
                    Label = "Emotional",
                    Confidence = 1
                }
            }
        },
        new PostModel
        {
            ProjectId = "3",
            Language = "en",
            PostDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            Profiles = new List<Profile>
            {
                new Profile
                {
                    Label = "Lazy",
                    Confidence = 3
                }
            }
        },
        new PostModel
        {
            ProjectId = "3",
            Language = "en",
            PostDate = new DateTime(2017, 6, 11, 8, 5, 1, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            Profiles = new List<Profile>()
        }
    };

    client.IndexMany(posts);
    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    var postModels = client.Search<PostModel>(s => s
        .Query(q =>
        {
            QueryContainer query = q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.ProjectId)
                    .Query("3")
                );

            query = query && q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .MustNot(bm => bm
                        .Nested(n => n
                            .Path(p => p.Profiles)
                            .Query(qn => qn
                                .Exists(m => m
                                    .Field(f => f.Profiles)
                                )
                            )
                        )               
                    )           
            );

            return query;
        }));
}

public class Profile 
{
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public int Confidence { get; set; }

}

public class PostModel
{
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }

    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

    public List<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

This returns just the one document with projectId `3` and no profiles

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.47000363,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "post",
        "_type" : "postmodel",
        "_id" : "qeNF72ABeLoaZkUgC2Xh",
        "_score" : 0.47000363,
        "_source" : {
          "projectId" : "3",
          "language" : "en",
          "postDate" : "2017-06-11T08:05:01Z",
          "profiles" : [ ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With [operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) on queries, the query can be expressed more succinctly

```
var postModels = client.Search<PostModel>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.ProjectId)
            .Query("3")
        ) && !q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.Profiles)
            .Query(qn => qn
                .Exists(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Profiles)
                )
            )
        )               
    )
);
```

Comment: referring to your solution, i have come up with a similar solution for my Profile query which is;

`query = query && q.Bool(b => b.MustNot(mn => mn.Nested(n => n
  .Path(p => p.Profiles).Query(nq => nq.Bool(qb => qb
  .Filter(bf => bf.Exists(fe => fe.Field(ef => ef.Profiles.First().Label))))))));`

I have tried your solution as well which worked perfectly fine. Thank you for your effort and your answer.